# Mutate state with dynamic keys in CreateSlice method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit in my application, where I want to update state with dynamic keys(**state[keys]**). I am getting error as **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'RootFormState'**

For example:

```
//someSlice.ts
interface FormState<T> {
  isValid: boolean;
  answer: T;
}
interface RootFormState {
  breakfast: FormState<Array>;
  lunch: FormState<string>;
  dinner: FormState<Array>;
}

const initialState:RootFormState = {
  breakfast: {
    isValid: false,
    answer: []
  },
  lunch: {
    isValid: false,
    answer: ""
  },
  dinner: {
    isValid: false,
    answer: []
  }
}

const foodSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'food',
  initialState,
  reduce: {
    updateAnswer: (state, action) => {
      const {id, answer} = action.payload;
      state[id].answer = answer;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Which line is giving you that error? You have other errors in the code shown here that need to be fixed first. `Array` is not a valid type—it takes a type argument, e.g. `Array<string>`. In `createSlice` you have a key called `reduce` but this should be `reducers`. Can you share a code sample that reproduces the problem you are having?

Comment: Yes, it is reducers. I am getting error here, "state[id].answer = answer"

Answer (score 0):

RTK exports a `PayloadAction` type you can use it to type the `action` parameter of the reducer.

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

interface FormState<T> {
  isValid: boolean;
  answer: T;
}
interface RootFormState {
  breakfast: FormState<Array<string>>;
  lunch: FormState<string>;
  dinner: FormState<Array<string>>;
}

const initialState: RootFormState = {
  breakfast: { isValid: false, answer: [] },
  lunch: { isValid: false, answer: '' },
  dinner: { isValid: false, answer: [] },
};

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
const foodSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'food',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateAnswer: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{ id: keyof RootFormState; answer: ValueOf<RootFormState>['answer'] }>,
    ) => {
      const { id, answer } = action.payload;
      state[id].answer = answer;
    },
  },
});
```